# Springdoc allow authenticated access to rest controllers with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, springdoc

I have Spring Security in my Project and it requires documentation through `springdoc version 1.4.3`. My requirement is to be able to get response from swagger-ui.html after authentication. Currently I can see the swagger-ui.html page but upon authentication calling any rest controller gives me access error. My requirement is that I should be able to get data from my controllers after user has authenticated.

Here is a sample curl url that gets generated which works on `cmd` but not on swagger-ui.html

```
curl -X GET "localhost:8080/api/employees/" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Bearer <token> -H "Cookie: token=<token>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your have configured the security using the OpenAPI annotations as well:

- @SecurityRequirement  Lists the required security schemes to execute this operation.
- @SecurityScheme   Defines a security scheme that can be used by the operations.

More explanations are available here:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations

Here is sample working code:

- https://github.com/springdoc/sample-springdoc-openapi-oauth2